# Characterize matrices that leave iterates of a point inside a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Fix a subspace $X \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and a vector $v \in X$. Consider the set of irreducible matrices $M$ with the property that $\left\{ v, Mv, M^{2}v, \ldots \right\}$ all lie in $X$.

Is there a nice characterization of such matrices? (By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, it's enough that $v, Mv, M^{2} v, \ldots, M^{n-1}v$ lie in $X$.)

Ideally, the characterization would be amenable to doing some concrete calculations in simple cases. I'm particularly interested in those matrices $M$ for which the entire subspace $X$ is *not* invariant.